# Counting occurences of a word in one cell, only if another cell has a specific word in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

As the title says I have a spreadsheet where I am gathering real time data about patients being tracked and transported in real life Aircraft Crashes or Active Shooter situations.

What I would like is this:

1. Count the amount of times the word "RED" occurs in Column D, only when it says "BIRV - Baylor Medical Center - Irving" in that same row of column G.

So my end state would be a cell, on another sheet which could count all my red patients at a specific hospital.

The goal is for the EMT to receive a count of Red and Yellow beds at each hospital.
This will be entered into  cells on Sheet 3 manually.
As EMTs enter patient info into a google form that populates Sheet 2, Sheet 1 will simultaneously keep a count of the number of Red and Yellow Patients he has sent to each individual hospital and then also subtract those numbers from the available beds which were entered on Sheet 3.

Example: Baylor Irving says they have 10 Red Beds and 10 Yellow Beds for patients, the Transport Officer enters that in the Bed Availability Tracker.
Patients start getting dispatched to various hospitals, but as he sends say 3 red patients and 4 yellow patients to Baylor Irving that 10/10 number would count down to 7/6. This way when he had sent 10 reds and yellows to Baylor Irving the counter would show 0/0 beds available and he would know not to send any more patients to that hospital.

Right now I am trying the code:

```
=COUNTA('Digital Patient Tracking Board'!D:D=ʺREDʺ,'Digital Patient Tracking Board'!G:G=ʺBIRV - Baylor Medical Center - Irvingʺ)
```

But I think I need some kind of VLOOKUP formula instead because this is just counting the incidents of "RED" ... I would post pictures but I don't have enough Rep.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you looking for a count of the total lines where cell D is "RED" and cell G is "BIRV" or might there be multiple instances of "RED" in cell D.  Look at COUNTIF() or COUNTIFS().

Comment: Yes to both questions. For example there could be 100 RED's, but Column G would be one of many potential hospitals. I'm hoping to count how many "RED" patients for sent to each specific hospital. Cooper's advice below solved the problem, I was very close to it, but was missing crucial characters to make mine work. He got it solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this.

```
=countifs(D:D,"*RED*",D:D,"*BIRV - Baylor Medical Center - Irving*")
```

Comment: Fantastic, that worked. I was so close to it, I think I even tried a very close variation of this but I didn't have the *'s and so it didn't work and I gave up on it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Actually I'd been all around the problem and finally slowed down to read  the all of the comments in the documentation for the command and I realized that all I needed was right there.  Good luck with your work.